# partially initialized module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, email

**I am trying to make my first email sender, here's the code:**

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login("(testemail)", "(pass)")
server.sendmail(
  "(testemail)", 
  "(myemail)", 
  "this message is from python")
server.quit()
```

**It returns with this error:**

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

**For context, I did not save it as email.py**

Comment: Check there is any other file saved as email.py or not

Comment: No theres nothing

Comment: Whats your file name?

Comment: my file name goes by mailtest.py

Comment: Files with these names could cause this problem,  if they exist in the same directory as your script: `smtplib.py`, `email.py`, `datetime.py`, `sys.py`, `io.py`, `base64.py`, `hmac.py`, `copy.py`, `re.py`, `socket.py`.

Answer (score 5):

As snakecharmerb mentioned in a comment:

You should change the file name of any of the following files in your project:

- smtplib.py
- email.py
- datetime.py
- sys.py
- io.py
- base64.py
- hmac.py
- copy.py
- re.py
- socket.py.